# How to use condition for one to many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2

I have the following models:
**User** and **Booking** (booking has user_id that references User model in id)

I want to make a query to retrieve Bookings where bookings.starts_at > now

I want something like this:

```
User::with('bookings')->where('starts_at' , '>' time())->get();
```

but where condition is applied on User and hence it causes an exception because User does not have starts_at.

How to solve this issue while still using Eloquent class?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This in controller:

Load  table user and table bookings joined on user_id where ' bookings.starts_at '>' 2015-07-04 '.

```
User::with(['bookings'=>function($query){
            $query->where('starts_at' , '>', date('Y-m-d'));
          }])->get();
```

Put your models into Models folder.

Model for user:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
     protected $table = 'users';
     protected $fillable = array('name','last_name');

  public function bookings() {
      return $this->hasMany('Bookings', 'user_id');
  }
}
```

model for bookings

start_at format should be year: month : date

```
class Bookings extends Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'bookings';
  protected $fillable = array('id','booking','user_id','start_at');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answers my question.