# How to use condition for one to many relationship in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798095/how-to-use-condition-for-one-to-many-relationship-in-laravel) and its work well, but when I try to put a variable its give me syntax error.

Here's my Code:

```
$ot_start = $request->ot_start;
$ot_end = $request->ot_end;
$ot_list = OTMain::with(['otmain_many_otline'=>function($query){
        $query ->where('time_from', '>=', date('d/M/Y H:i:s', strtotime($ot_start . ' 00:00:00.000')))
            ->where('time_from', '<=', date('d/M/Y H:i:s', strtotime($ot_end .' 23:59:59.000')));
        }])->get();
```

Print Screen:
[image]

I don't know why **$ot_start** and **$ot_end** getting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous function `function($query)` **knows nothing** about `$ot_start`, `$ot_end`. That's why phpstorm marks these variables, as they're undefined in function's scope.

You need to pass'em explicitly with `use` word:

```
OTMain::with(['otmain_many_otline'=>function($query) use ($ot_start, $ot_end) {
```

Now, these variables are available in function.

Answer (score 2):

Add use():

```
 $ot_list = OTMain::with(['otmain_many_otline'=>function($query) use (ot_start , ot_end ){
                         $query ->where('time_from', '>=', date('d/M/Y H:i:s', strtotime($ot_start . ' 00:00:00.000')))
                                 ->where('time_from', '<=', date('d/M/Y H:i:s', strtotime($ot_end .' 23:59:59.000')));
                         }])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use closures (anonymous functions) you need pass your variables by `use`. Eg:

```
$ot_start = $request->ot_start;
$ot_end = $request->lot_end;
$ot_list = OTMain::with(['otmain_many_otline'=>function($query) use($ot_start,$ot_end){
    $query ->where('time_from', '>=', date('d/M/Y H:i:s', strtotime($ot_start . ' 00:00:00.000')))
        ->where('time_from', '<=', date('d/M/Y H:i:s', strtotime($ot_end .' 23:59:59.000')));
    }])->get();
```